# assert string array not equal but appears to be

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have 2 string arrays that appear to be the same when I inspect them. Am I using the wrong Assert method?

```
//Arrange
string[] expected = new[] { "Widget A", "Widget B" };
string[] actual;
//Act
actual = api.GetIncidents(credentials);
//Assert
Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);

Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<System.String[]>. Actual:<System.String[]>.
```

Comment: Which unit testing framework are you using?

Comment: Microsoft Test Framework in VS2008 SP1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [CollectionAssert.AreEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243736%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method and generally the [CollectionAssert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert_methods%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) class when asserting on collections:

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```